# How to retrieve count values as multiple columns using group by in single query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a complex MySQL query. My actual query is more complex than I mentioned below.

I have a table named `example` and columns are `id`, `name`, `option_1`, `option_2` . Of course `id` column is PK . I want to retrieve like this:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,count(`option_1`),count(`option_2`)
```

My problem is I want to use `` "GROUP BY `id`" `` for `` count(`option_1`) `` and `` "GROUP BY `name`" `` for `` count(`option_2`) `` respectively. Now I have to break down it into multiple code in my php code.

How can I achieve what I want in a single query?

Comment: It would be good if you provide some sample data and expected result out of those given sample data.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df1a/1) Is this what you want to do?

Comment: What is the relationship between values of `id` and `name`. That is, how do you know which `id` and `name` values should appear together on each row of your resultset? Please consider showing a few rows of sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make a ton of sense. You want option 1 grouped by `id` and option 2 grouped by `name`, and you want to show all four columns in one result set.

First of all, if `id` is a primary key, then the count will just be the number of rows in the table since there will be no duplicate ids.

Second, even if `id` wasn't a primary key, and there were duplicate values, the grouping is different, so the counts represented in your result set would be grouped incorrectly.

---

Given that `id` is a primary key, perhaps your intention is actually to get a total count of the rows in the table. Perhaps this query would suit your needs?

```
SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(option_2) AS options
FROM
  example
GROUP BY
  name
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Total' AS name,
  COUNT(*) AS options
FROM
  example
```

This should get you a count of all the `option_2` values, grouped by name, with the final row having a `name` of 'Total' and the count being the total number of rows in the table.

Aside from that, I'm not sure you're going to find the answer you're looking for due to the problems you would encounter matching up groupings.

Comment: What means 'Total' AS name . I am not clear with that . But you query makes sense .

Comment: @Waiyan: That just means to use the literal string `'Total'` as the value returned in that column, and alias the column name as `name`. So if you just did a simple query that said `SELECT 'Total' AS name;`, your result would be one column, named `name` and one row, with the value being `'Total'`.